# Microsoft Word 2013 failing to print checkbox character

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, fonts, microsoft-word-2013

In my .docx file, I have a checklist typed out like this:

```
☐ Read the prep doc 
☐ Look up client notes
```

**But when I print the document, the boxes don't appear.**  Everything else about the document prints correctly.

By the way, I've highlighted all of the text and set it as *Times New Roman* font.

However, even after doing that, if I move the cursor to one of the checkboxes, I see that it remains set as *Segoe UI Symbol* font.

**How can I get Microsoft Word 2013 (on Windows) to correctly print this document *with* the boxes?**

See also: "ballot box" character (`&#9744;`) at http://graphemica.com/%E2%98%90

Comment: Is the behavior different when you use different print servers?  that is try printing to PDF, XPS, and or OneNote.  It may be an issue with the print driver.  I would also try a test page using different symbols and see if any of those print.

Comment: Try saving your document as PDF and print from there. Word seems to insert symbol only using some certain fonts, like Symbol and Segoe UI Symbol.

Comment: Your printer might not have the necessary font data - Windows tells the printer which characters to print, and the printer (supposedly) knows how they look. So it could be a printer driver issue - you can check that by printing to PDF. If it is shown inside the PDF, it is _not_ a word issue.

Comment: Good suggestions. The ☐ appears in the PDF generated by Word 2013. So I guess you are saying it is the fault of the drivers of my HP Deskjet 3050? Those drivers seem to be up to date though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I botched this question.  **Although I had been editing the document using Microsoft Word 2013 (on Windows), the file had been printed from Microsoft Word 2003 (on Mac).  That makes a big difference because that version of Word probably didn't have the Segoe UI Symbol font.**

So, on the Mac, I recently edited the ballot boxes to use a different font.  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/fontsupport.htm can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try save as, then click on "tools" in the bottom right. Click on save options. Then choose the check box stating:"Embed fonts in the file". Try printing upon saving, it should work now.